# Skipping Blank lines in read file python

Tags: python, readfile

Im working on a very long project, i have everything done with it, but in the file he wants us to read at the bottom there are empty spaces, legit just blank spaces that we aren't allowed to delete, to work on the project i deleted them because i have no idea how to get around it, so my current open/read looks like this

```
      file = open("C:\\Users\\bh1337\\Documents\\2015HomicideLog_FINAL.txt" , "r")
 lines=file.readlines()[1:]
 file.close()
```

What do i need to add to this to ignore blank lines? or to stop when it gets to a blank line?

Comment: line can have spaces or tabs and loooks like empty.

Comment: use `for line in file: if not line.strip(): print("it is empty line")`

Comment: Pretty sure an empty list has a `False` boolean value.

Answer (score 9):

You can check if they are empty:

```
file = open('filename')
lines = [line for line in file.readlines() if line.strip()]
file.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for line in file:
  if not line.strip():
    ... do something
```

Follwoing will be best for readinf files

```
with open("fname.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
      if not line.strip():
        ... do something
```

`With open` will takecare of file close.

If you want to ignore lines with only whitespace

Comment: When you say ...do something, can i just put the `file.close` there?

Comment: @BraydenHark the `with`   clause eliminates the need for explicit `file.close`

Comment: So what would i put in for the do something..? or could i just leave it blank there? Sorry im extremely new to coding, and i'm not sure its for me =/

Comment: using this method I'm getting an error " List index out of range" heres the code   `with open("C:\\Users\\Brayd\OneDrive\\Documents\\2015HomicideLog_FINAL.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        lines=file.readlines()[1:]
    if not line.strip():
        lines=file.readlines()[1:]`
Ive tried replacing the bottom command with `file.close()` and `print("it is empty line")` and nothing seems to be working

Comment: Runs perfectly fine if i delete the spaces @ the bottom of the .txt file, but the file my Prof wants us to read has whitespaces at the bottom, any idea? @backtrack

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple way to skip the empty lines:

```py
with open(file) as f_in: 
    lines = list(line for line in (l.strip() for l in f_in) if line)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. One way is to use the `lines` list and remove all the elements e such that e.strip() is empty. This way, you can delete all lines with just whitespaces.
2. Other way is to use `f.readline` instead of `f.readlines()` which will read the file line by line. First, initialize an empty list. If the present read-in line, after stripping, is empty, ignore that line and continue to read the next line. Else add the read-in line to the list.

Hope this helps!