# Reading >2000 lines text file, but it stops at line 46 that is empty. Why?

Tags: python, parsing, newline

This problem only occurs when I include the print line I commented out below.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1:
    fname = "mbox-short.txt"
fh = open(fname)
i = 0
count = 0
with open(fname, 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        temp = line.split()
        #print(temp[0])
        count+=1 
        print(count)
```

Comment: Note: you can remove `fh = open(fname)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attempt to split an empty string it returns an empty list:

```
>>> ''.split()
[]
```

For this reason, attempting to access `temp[0]` throws an `IndexError` exception and your processing stops.  You could fix it like so:

```
if not line: # line is blank
  continue
```

Answer (score 0):

When a line is empty, `temp` is also empty. There is no `temp[0]` to print, and Python terminates with an uncaught `IndexError`.

Comment: this [so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647881/skipping-blank-lines-in-read-file-python/40647964) has the answer